Getting "An error occured" when trying to remove a post from a "Saves" list
When I try to remove any post saved in one of the "Saves" list by clicking the orange label, I get a message in red saying "An error occured" and the post stays in the list.

Update:
As of now, it looks like the bug has been fixed.

maybe related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/404563/unable-to-unsave-posts-when-showing-them-again-or-even-just-after-being-refresh/404564#404564

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks. It seems to be related indeed. And the workaround posted there works for me as well.

As mentioned in a comment above, this issue is related to a bug accross all stack-exchange sites.
The meta post linked above proposes the following workaround:
A post can be removed from the "Saves" list from the main "Saves" page by clicking "Unsave" as shown below.

